# Pouch query is blocking dom

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, web-audio-api, pouchdb

here is my code to test pouchdb queries:

Main file:

```
var myAudio = new Audio("http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%    20Major.mp3");
myAudio.play();
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.postMessage("start worker");
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
   console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
}, false);
```

Worker.js:

```
importScripts("pouchdb-5.2.0.min.js");

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    queryDocs();
}, false);

function queryDocs(){
    localDB.allDocs({
        include_docs: true,
        attachments: true
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        self.postMessage("returned docs:", response);
   });
}
```

Steps:
    1.I am running this in a node.js app, which is playing an audio.
    2.Now , while playing audio I have to query pouchDB.I am limiting the cpu to 60% for all instances of the app with command "cpulimit -p processId -l 60.(To test it with low configuration.So that It should work on low configured machine without stuttering)

Issue:
If "cpulimit" command is not used then it's working fine means I am able to query the pouchdb without audio stuttering , but if I am limiting the cpu using command "cpulimit"., then audio is stuttering.

Requirements:
How can I make it work on low configured machine without stuttering?

Comment: This happens due to sync behavior of your jquery call to db

Answer (score 0):

PouchDB cannot block the DOM if it is running in a Web Worker. However, streaming audio in the main thread main may cause DOM-blocking. You can use the Timeline view in Chrome to see what's running on the main thread and therefore what's blocking the DOM.

Another thing that can block the DOM is sending large amounts of data from the background thread to the main thread. In your query above it looks like you're using `attachments: true` but not `binary: true`. This means that PouchDB is pulling base64 string data and sending it across the wire in `postMessage`. A more efficient choice is probably to use a Blob, convert it to an ArrayBuffer (e.g. using [blob-util](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util)), and then send that across as a [Transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable).